# How to specify function for stub when using minitest mocha?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

Is it possible to specify which `find_by!` exception is raised in the following example (I want the second one to be raised, not the first):

```
def self.test
  Instance.stubs(:find_by!).raises(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)

  begin
    function_one
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    puts 'Failure'
  end

  begin
    function_two
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    puts 'Success'
  end
end

def self.function_one
  Model.find_by!(id: 1)
end

def self.function_two
  Model.find_by!(id: 1)
end
```

*Assume `id: 1` does not exist. As in the example, also assume these will be static class functions, but please mention any differences in the case that add `any_instance` will not be enough for instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```rb
Instance.stubs(:find_by!).returns('result').then.raises(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
```

Comment: This seems like a workaround, no? I figured to get good code coverage in most scenarios, they would provide something like `expects(:function_two).stubs(:find_by!).raises(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)`. Is what I am trying to do not standard or strange? How else would we test the line with `puts 'Success'` in the rescue? Is this a situation where I have to weight rewriting the code to make it testable?

Comment: With this example, it's hard to understand what you're trying to test there. Maybe you can post the actual functionality you want to test so that it's easier to advise something?

Comment: The code I have in particular will only confuse things I'm afraid and is too lengthy (spread out) to be concise. This example is the best representation I could provide. This doesn't seem to be a crazy use case.